# String Arrays in Assembly 8086

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16

As part of a school project (majoring in Computer Science and we learn assembly language for part of our grade, starting with 8086 right now) I have to make... something using what we've "learned"  (our teacher gave us a list of commands and told us to teach ourselves, with his help obviously) until the end of the month.

So I made a "game" where you are this smiley guy and you gotta go through this maze, with stars as obstacles that bring you back to the starting point and '>' as the marker for next level.

The levels are just text that I print to the screen, each step comparing the next input with a wall/star/'>' thing and then if it's a  star it resets your position, if it's a wall you stay in your place and if it's a '>' thingy then it prints the next level. It all works except the next part of next level.

[Here's the Pastebin, with my problem detailed and pointed out.](http://pastebin.com/ZnVBJMTA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: `inc  mazesIndex` you need to increase mazesIndex by maze size (`49 * 10 + 1 = 491 bytes`) instead of by 1

Comment: So would adding a mazeSize 16 bit variable and then doing `add mazeIndex, mazeSize` solve my issue? Also, how would I calculate the mazeSize? I'd hate having it hard coded...

Comment: @ItamarReif, you don't have to have it hard-coded. Assuming your maze is of constant type, you can put label at the beginning of the second maze and then to calculate the difference between the starting address of maze1 and starting address of maze0. If the length may vary, then you will have to measure the string length in run-time

Comment: What does 'constant type' mean? And if I understand correctly I put, say, a '#' sign at (0;0) in each member of the mazes array and then I calculate the amount of characters between each '#'? How would I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I meant constant size, of course. If the size may vary, you need to calculate it in run-time. Another option is to build a look-up table, which will contain pointers to the mazes themselves. If you prefer to calculate in run-time, then you don't need to add any special character, because you already have one - '$' at the end of each maze. So when you start the maze, you can scan the array until you find '$' and remember its position. Then, when you want to switch to the next maze, set mazeIndex to previously remembered position + 1 (in order to skip '$' character itself)

Comment: `whichMaze:mov  si, mazesIndex
mov  bh, mazes[si]                
                 mov  byte ptr indexChar, bh
                 cmp  bh, '$'
                 je   endOfMaze
                 jne  nextChar                 

    endOfMaze:   inc  $Count    
                 mov  dx, mazeCount
                 cmp  $Count, dx 
                 je   fin
                 jne  nextChar                  

    nextChar:    inc  mazesIndex
                 loop whichMaze
            
    fin:         inc  mazesIndex
                 mov  $Count, 0h
                 ret` something like that?

Comment: [I solved it!](http://pastebin.com/ktXqEuxe) But now the cursor starts displaying at the end of the maze: http://i.imgur.com/0i9ZMls.png

Comment: @Denis Itskovich. Where did you get those numbers? I got (48*10)+45+1.   To Itamar Reif. For lines 188-189 : Since *mazeCount* and *$count* are both variables they reside in memory. The processor cannot compare these straight up. For line 194 : You didn't setup CX so you cannot use LOOP here! A simple JMP is ok.

Comment: @ItamarReif, I didn't calculate well. It should be 48*10+1.

Comment: @user3144770 Oh, thanks!

DenisItskovich Thanks for all the help, I solved this thanks to you.